# usergrid 2.0 database setup error

Tags: installation, usergrid

I am trying to get usergrid 2.0 running. 
I built the sources and deployed to tomcat. the status shows usergrid is running
when i try to setup database (http://localhost:8080/system/database/setup) it results in an error.  "Error migrating Core Persistence"

Error:

{"error":"runtime","timestamp":1234567890,"duration":0,"error_description":"Error migrating Core Persistence","exception":"java.lang.RuntimeException"}

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

you must be running cassandra 1.2.1* and Elastic Search current version.  Also you cannot upgrade from a 1.0 cluster.

Comment: In the usergrid-default.properties file there is an option : cassandra.version = 1.2 , if I change it to 2.0 or 2.1 will it work?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a variety of things wrong. Maybe your Cassandra and ElasticSearch instances are not available, maybe you have specified the wrong hostnames/ports for them in your usergrid-deployment.properties file, maybe your properties file is not in the Tomcat classpath (or maybe there you are hitting a bug in Usergrid).

Since you see a RuntimeException, there is probably a stack trace in Tomcat's catalina.out log file that could provide information to help you diagnose the problem.